# How to fix bad CSV syntax from Microsoft Access 2007

Tags: csv, ms-access

An export of my Microsoft Access 2007 table to CSV has formatting issues. I don't think it is following CSV standards. I have found a few online tools which will check syntax, and which are finding many errors. But how can I overcome this? I need a clean CSV export so I can import that data into another web app. I haven't found any online tools which will correct bad CSV syntax.

Comment: Please provide example of formatting issues.

Comment: My CSV has 60,000+ rows of data. I ran it through csvlint.io/validation and it came up with 14,856 errors. Some examples: unclosed row, empty row, unexpected whitespace, missing columns, stray quote, etc.

Comment: Would need example of raw data - records that export with the errors. Can upload db file to fileshare site such as Box.com and post link.

Comment: https://secure.bbdesign.com/bbdesign/tbl_inventory2.csv

Comment: I'm afraid it will be quite hard to cleanup this mess. If it's possible, try to request export in other format. Tab separated text format should work better. xlsx would be ideal. If not - most of problems is with new lines and quotes in text values. May be somebody can advice cleaning utilities, but VBA function, which converts this to tab separated will be not too complicated

Comment: I will try tab-delimited and see how that goes.

Comment: TAB-delimited may have solved this.